# How do I pass an empty variable value to Date() object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I created a function:

```
fD = D => new Date(D).toDateString().toLocaleString("en-US", {
            timeZone: "America/New_York"
        )};
```

Problem is that sometimes I want to use `fD()` to `invoke Date()` with a string value parameter (D), while also, at other times, being able to invoke `fD()` as is with no parameter at all to trigger the `Date()` object (versus invoking `Date()` as `Date(D)`. Using the function, as written above (invoked as `fD()` with no parameter), returns an error.

```
fD = D => (D ? new Date(D) : new Date()).toDateString().toLocaleString("en-US", {
            timeZone: "America/New_York"
        });
```

I fixed it with the code above, but I don't like the redundancy of having to put "new Date()" twice in the same line.

I tried the following variations in an attempt to shorten it...

```
fD = D = (D = null) => new Date(D).toDateString().toLocaleString("en-US", {
            timeZone: "America/New_York"
        )};
```

...But, this creates a date of 1970 when `fD()` is invoke without the parmeter.

Any advice on how to shorten the code and to avoid using redundant `Date()` objects?

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: _"I don't like the redundancy of having to put "new Date()" twice in the same line"_ - Use `if...else...` and place each block on a new line, use `Date.parse()`, ...

Comment: _"Any advice on how to shorten the code and to avoid using redundant Date() objects?"_ -> https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sometimes a little redundancy improves readability and saves time.

Comment: But can I fix it with an assignment operator (such as the new ones added in ES2020? I want to do something like this.. D ?? (where ?? would be an operator that assigns D to D only if there is a D)

Comment: Your issue is that parameters in a function definition are always assigned a value during function initialisation, prior to execution (see [*ECMAScript Standard Built-in Objects*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-standard-built-in-objects), paragraph 4). If no value is passed to a parameter, it's given the value *undefined*, i.e. in `function(x){}` *arguments.length* is always >= 1 and *x* always has a value, so you can't distinguish between no value being passed and and the *undefined* value being passed. Default parameters are the only fix.

Answer (score 0):

> I created a function:
>
> ```
> fD = D => new Date(D).toDateString().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "America/New_York" )};
> ```

[*toDateString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) returns a string, calling *toLocaleString* on a string does not support the *timeZone* option, nor will language "en-US" affect the format, so the call to *toLocaleString* does nothing useful.

This scenario is the reason for [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

```js
let fd = (d = new Date()) => d.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: 'America/New_York', timeZoneName:'long'});

// No value passed
console.log(fd());
// Value passed
console.log(fd(new Date(2021,0,1)));
```

PS By convention, variable names starting with a capital letter are used for constructors, so use lower case for other cases.

PPS There is no *String.prototype.toLocaleString*, calling *toLocaleString* on a string defaults to [*Object.prototype.toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString).

Comment: We’re getting closer to what I to do. The reason I have use the .toDateString() method is because elsewhere in my code, I want to compare two dates. It doesn’t have to be a string. They could both be Date objects. I want to check if imported date data (formatted as 02/13/2021) matches today’s date. And both dates have to be converted to EST time zone. So, the function has to convert what goes into it into the correct time zone and reformatted so that the code could check if the date being entered into it is today. Is there’s a better to do this without first converting these dates to strings?

Comment: @PeterJayAltschuler—that is a whole series of questions. Dates like 2021-02-21 don’t have a timezone and can be compared as strings if formatted correctly. Post a question for what your actually trying to do and help might be more targeted. :-)